# Identify this Gitane road bike

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I yesterday bought this bike from Offer up for $100 and want to know more about the bicycle. Can someone please help me get the model, type and year of this bicycle from the picture below.

[image]

Comment: As for price, its worth what someone wants to pay for it.

Answer (score 4):

As @Paparazzi said it appears to be a Gitane bike, from looking through the [product catalogues on the Gitane USA site](http://www.gitaneusa.com/catalogues02.asp) I suspect it's a 1984 Gran Tour ([from page 5 of the french catalogue](http://www.gitaneusa.com/images/catalog/1984/Page_04.jpg)) as this style of logo appears to have only been used for the early 80s and this model is the only model that has the bar end shifters/is advertised in the same colour.

Comment: Yep, a dead-on match to the Gran Tour in your second link, except that there's a slight difference in shifter cable routing, suggesting a few years after 1984.  1984 would be about the earliest for bar end shifters,I suspect.  Note that the wheels have most certainly been updated.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Gitane touring bicycle.  By searching you should be able to match a year.

Probably from the 90's as threadless stems came on about 2000.

If is rolls $100 is a good price.

Comment: Come on down vote what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the Gran Tour; I have an unalatered version.  Originals had hand brake cables going out the top of the levers, but the rubber perished; looks like this is why these have been replaced.  Obviously wheels are not original either.

Can't really tell from the photo, but it doesn't look like it has the stronglight crankset. No idea why someone would change it over, would be a lot of cost/work.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might like to have a look at our brief [tour] to help you get the most out of your time here.